# How To Insert Data Into Temp Table From Different Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to insert data into a temp table from 2 tables from 2 different databases. This is because I need the data from one to create a unique identifier in the other.

This is what I currently have:

```
-- Create Temp table for data manipulation
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Staging') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Staging

CREATE TABLE #Staging
(
    InitialChildValue nvarchar(4000),
    PropertyNumber nvarchar(10),
    NewYearValue nvarchar(2),
    NewChildValue nvarchar(4000)
)

--Insert initial data into temp table
INSERT INTO #Staging (InitialChildValue, PropertyNumber, NewYearValue, NewChildValue)
    SELECT combo.ChildValue, combo.TABLE_NO, '22' AS YEAR, ''
    FROM 
        (SELECT ChildValue, NULL AS TABLE_NO 
         FROM [DB1].[Version].[Token] 
         WHERE DeletedTransactionKey IS NULL
         UNION
         SELECT NULL AS ChildValue, TABLE_NO 
         FROM [DB2].[dbo].[Notice]
         -- WHERE NOTICE_RUN_CTR = @NoticeRunCTR
        ) combo
```

But this query returns something like this:

| ChildValue | TABLE_NO | YEAR | (empty) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 22 |  |
| 2 |  | 22 |  |
| 3 |  | 22 |  |
|  | a | 22 |  |
|  | b | 22 |  |
|  | c | 22 |  |

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

| ChildValue | TABLE_NO | YEAR | (empty) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 22 |  |
| 2 | b | 22 |  |
| 3 | c | 22 |  |

Further on in my stored procedure, I would then go on to create an ID like "FY1a22" and update the Token table in DB1 based on the initial ChildValue already stored in the temp table.

e.g. loosely written as:

```
UPDATE DB1.Notice
SET ChildValue = NewChildValue
WHERE ChildValue = #Staging.ChildValue
```

(I know that is not correct syntax, I'm just shorthand writing it)

There is unfortunately no link between the databases which is why I'm attempting to do it this way.

Any ideas or suggestions would be sorely appreciated.

Comment: And apparently i don't know how to format tables in questions :)

Comment: You need to provide how the data from the union statements relate. If they are ordered the same way without gaps or there is a foreign key relation then the answer will be easy. If they are heaps with no relation to each other then the answer will be hard to imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `row_number()` to generate a sequence number and use it to join the rows from `Token` with `Notice`

Seems like there is no relationship on how to link `ChildValue` with `Table_No`. Based on the expected result provided, I am assuming it will goes by it's value

```
SELECT t.ChildValue, n.TABLE_NO, '22' AS YEAR, ''
FROM 
(
    SELECT ChildValue, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ChildValue)
    FROM   [DB1].[Version].[Token] 
    WHERE DeletedTransactionKey IS NULL
) t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TABLE_NO,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_NO) 
    FROM [DB2].[dbo].[Notice]
) n
ON t.RN = n.RN
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly. You are correct that there is no relationship between the two columns/tables/databases so there was no care/concern about which ChildValue was allocated to which Table_No. The addition of a row number and joining on that gave exactly what was needed. Thank you so much.