# Retrieve field from table B based on date in table A

Tags: sql, teradata

I have table **A** which contains tasks and completion dates and table **B** that contains the Fiscal Year, and production cycles. This is the structure of table **B**:

| FY | Cycle | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2 | 2021-03-31 | 2021-06-30 |
| 2021 | 3 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-31-12 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 2022 | 2 | 2022-03-31 | 2022-06-30 |

What I want to do is to retrieve `Cycle` based on whether my date in Table **A** falls between a `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

My resultset would be my date and then the cycle. Eg.

Task with date `2022-02-22 08:43:44.002000` falls between `2022-01-01` and `2022-03-31` so I want to retrieve `cycle` 1 in FY 2022.

Since I cannot join this table directly and check it with a `BETWEEN` I tried to create a CTE containing the entire table of **B** but then I kind of got stuck with the next steps. There must be a better approach than the code below (which doesn't work).

```
    WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM B
)
CASE WHEN task_date >= (SELECT StartDate FROM cte) AND task_date < (SELECT EndDate FROM CTE)
```

Comment: `I cannot join this table directly and check it with a BETWEEN` - why not?

Answer (score 1):

Could i perhaps point you to a question i've asked in the past where i was trying to link data from 2 tables in separate databases where there was no link between them. The answer from Squirrel was able to give me exactly what i needed:

[How To Insert Data Into Temp Table From Different Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842781/how-to-insert-data-into-temp-table-from-different-databases)

It basically involves adding a Row Number to each table and joining on that Row Number. You might be able to use that logic to get what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed it in another way though. I changed the table so that it includes a flag for the current Cycle and then added a `WHERE` in my `CASE` statement. That returned all the tasks in the current cycle.

Comment: @Adrian Cool! Glad to hear it. Good luck with the rest of your task :)